# Multiple definitions of a function template

Tags: c++, templates, linker

Suppose a header file defines a function template.  Now suppose two implementation files `#include` this header, and each of them has a call to the function template.  In both implementation files the function template is instantiated with the same type.

```
// header.hh
template <typename T>
void f(const T& o)
{
    // ...
}

// impl1.cc
#include "header.hh"

void fimpl1()
{
    f(42);
}

// impl2.cc
#include "header.hh"

void fimpl2()
{
    f(24);
}
```

One may expect the linker would complain about multiple definitions of `f()`.  Specifically, if `f()` wouldn't be a template then that would indeed be the case.

- How come the linker doesn't complain about multiple definitions of `f()`?
- Is it specified in the standard that the linker must handle this situation gracefully?  In other words, can I always count on programs similar to the above to compile and link?
- If the linker can be clever enough to disambiguate a set of function template instantiations, why can't it do the same for regular functions, given they are identical as is the case for instantiated function templates?

Comment: Title is misleading... how about "multiple instantiations" instead?  Or "instantiations in separate translation units"?

Comment: I have clarified the question.  It's a rather broad question, so I divided it into smaller questions.  Perhaps I should split these into several SO questions?

Comment: I don't see "multiple definitions" of f() in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to support C++, the linker is smart enough to recognize that they are all the same function and throws out all but one.

EDIT: clarification:
The linker doesn't compare function contents and determine that they are the same.
Templated functions are marked as such and the linker recognizes that they have the same signatures.

Comment: But not smart enough to recognize this when f() is not a template?

Comment: It's not allowed to, except for templates.

Comment: It does this for inline functions, too - if it decides not to inline them.

Comment: @Mark Ransom If I understand you correctly, for inline functions, if the compiler does not intend to inline them, it will complains multiple definitions of the normal fucntion?Am I right?

Comment: @John no.  If you include the `inline` keyword in the definition, it indicates that you might define the function in multiple translation units (source files) so the compiler expects this and doesn't complain.  You are still expected to adhere to the One Definition Rule and ensure all the inline function definitions are identical - there's no requirement for it to detect if they aren't.

Answer (score 6):

The Gnu C++ compiler's manual has [a good discussion of this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Template-Instantiation.html).  An excerpt:

> C++ templates are the first language
>   feature to require more intelligence
>   from the environment than one usually
>   finds on a UNIX system. Somehow the
>   compiler and linker have to make sure
>   that each template instance occurs
>   exactly once in the executable if it
>   is needed, and not at all otherwise.
>   There are two basic approaches to this
>   problem, which are referred to as the
>   Borland model and the Cfront model.
>
> ### Borland model
>
> Borland C++ solved the template
>   instantiation problem by adding the
>   code equivalent of common blocks to
>   their linker; the compiler emits
>   template instances in each translation
>   unit that uses them, and the linker
>   collapses them together. The advantage
>   of this model is that the linker only
>   has to consider the object files
>   themselves; there is no external
>   complexity to worry about. This
>   disadvantage is that compilation time
>   is increased because the template code
>   is being compiled repeatedly. Code
>   written for this model tends to
>   include definitions of all templates
>   in the header file, since they must be
>   seen to be instantiated.
>
> ### Cfront model
>
> The AT&T C++ translator, Cfront,
>   solved the template instantiation
>   problem by creating the notion of a
>   template repository, an automatically
>   maintained place where template
>   instances are stored. A more modern
>   version of the repository works as
>   follows: As individual object files
>   are built, the compiler places any
>   template definitions and
>   instantiations encountered in the
>   repository. At link time, the link
>   wrapper adds in the objects in the
>   repository and compiles any needed
>   instances that were not previously
>   emitted. The advantages of this model
>   are more optimal compilation speed and
>   the ability to use the system linker;
>   to implement the Borland model a
>   compiler vendor also needs to replace
>   the linker. The disadvantages are
>   vastly increased complexity, and thus
>   potential for error; for some code
>   this can be just as transparent, but
>   in practice it can be very difficult
>   to build multiple programs in one
>   directory and one program in multiple
>   directories. Code written for this
>   model tends to separate definitions of
>   non-inline member templates into a
>   separate file, which should be
>   compiled separately.
>
> When used with GNU ld version 2.8 or
>   later on an ELF system such as
>   GNU/Linux or Solaris 2, or on
>   Microsoft Windows, G++ supports the
>   Borland model. On other systems, G++
>   implements neither automatic model.

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less a special case just for templates.

The compiler only generates the template instantiations that are actually used. Since it has no control over what code will be generated from other source files, it has to generate the template code once for each file, to make sure that the method gets generated at all.

Since it's difficult to solve this (the standard has an `extern` keyword for templates, but g++ doesn't implement it) the linker simply accepts the multiple definitions.