# Template implicit specialization & linkage, how it works?

Tags: c++, templates, module

Can one explain, when exactly template instantiation happens? assume we've {libA, libB}, one depends on another (for instance libA -> libB) & have A.h declare template class Foo { }; included in sources of both modules. next both sources use Foo; but where they will be code of this Foo; will it be in libA & used in libB? or mb both will implement Foo, but then what about duplicate symbols?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple definitions of a function template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235616/multiple-definitions-of-a-function-template)

Answer (score 0):

**1) libA and libB are static libraries:**
The code implementing the template instantiation will be in both libs. When the two libs are linked together, only one copy of the code will be in the final output. The linker is required to be smart enough to handle duplicate code resulting from template instantiation, so that no multiple-definition errors occur. This behavior is uniform across all C++ implementations. How this is achieved may vary from implementation to implementation. In Microsoft C++, this is achieved through [COMDAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976.aspx).

**2) libA and libB are DLL import libraries:**
In this case, the code implementing the template instantiation will not be in the libs anyway. So there is nothing special for the linker to do. The code will be in the DLLs instead, one copy per DLL.